# Add www to the secure url if www is not in that url in react js web application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, https

How can i add www in the url if www is not present in the secure url in `react js` web application.need to add some special handling if secure

```
if (req.secure) {
// request was via https, so do no special handling
next();
} else {
// request was via http, so redirect to https
res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
}
```

Comment: Do it using a web server.

Comment: It is hosted in AWS. i need to add some in the above code if the request is secure

Comment: btw, you can check if `req.headers.host.startsWith("www.")` then don't add `www` or add `www` in the `host`.

Comment: It is hosted on EC2

Comment: You can do it per the previous comment. And if it's on EC2 it should have a web server either Apache or NgInx

Comment: Node  server is using